# Analogy between Curie's Law and the Ideal Gas Law

Tags: thermodynamics, gas, ferromagnetism

I've been trying to derive Curie's Law from the Ideal Gas Law for a while, since numerous sites on the internet state that they are analogous.

However, if we apply the equivalences - $P \iff B$; $V \iff M$, we arrive at:

$$PV=KT \implies BM =CT,$$

which is totally different from Curie's Law. I would like to know where I am failing in my reasoning.

Comment: I've never heard of such a derivation, and I'd be surprised that it existed. While both laws are statistical in nature, the ideal gas law doesn't assume any magnetic property for the molecules, while Curie's law is explicitely based on magnetic properties. Moreover, I've never seen a $-P\leftrightarrow B$ and $V \leftrightarrow M$ equivalence, at least not motivated by physical arguments. Could you provide an example of such a claim?

Comment: Physics is not math.  The physics concepts drive the math.  The math concepts do not drive the physics.  Taking one functional form from physics and assuming that you can substitute variables and arrive at an analogous functional form from a different area of physics is not a valid assumption.

Comment: both the ideal gas law $pV=RT$ and Curie's law for paramagnetic materials $M=H\frac{C_m}{T}$ are *constitutive* laws, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie%27s_law There is no reason why you could make a substitution such as $p \to B=\mu H$ or $V \to M$ and expect anything useful from it. You can make some interesting derivations regarding heat capacities, etc., from the formal similarities of the equations $dU_{gas}=TdS-pdV$ and $dU_{mag}=TdS+HdB$ but not their constitutive relations.